# Has the English language changed since 1854?

Tags: american-english, old-english, books

I've started reading a book named Walden, published in 1854.  I am not a native English speaker, I am Persian, and I want to read this book for two reasons:
to improve my English and because I think I'll enjoy it.
But the words and the grammar the author uses look difficult for me and I presume it may have been written in Old English.  Am I right?

(**note:** *I'm reading this book with the help of a dictionary and I'm writing each word what I learn in a notebook.*)

Comment: It will not be written in modern English, and some of the expressions, and idiom could be difficult to understand even for a native speaker, though it will not be like reading Chaucer!. It belongs roughly to the era of Charles Dickens. However, you may wish to start with something a bit more recent if you are still hesitant with your English.

Comment: Motivation is a most powerful force in language learning. If you really like the book, you can plow through it and learn English. The grammar is not much different from today; the vocabulary: everyone 'reads from a dictionary' if reading unfamiliar material; the style of writing is bland to me, which means I think it's boring and can't read 5 pages without becoming restless. Mark Twain, who was born in 1835, is much more interesting.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Kermani.  All languages change as the years go by. New words are added and a few are forgotten.  The more contact with other languages and other peoples, the quicker the change.  But even isolated societies (rare nowadays) have their languages changed a bit in 100 years. Some of the words you'll find in "Walden; or Life in the Woods" are not used anymore and if you incorporate them into your vocabulary you'll certainly sound very strange to a native speaker.  I advise you to try easy reading material from the past forty years or so.

Comment: I once started reading Walden and gave it up.  I can't recall all the reasons, but I do recall that it was very tedious in places and some of the language was (50 years ago) awkward to a "modern" ear.  It's considered a classic, but there are better books.  (I'd recommend Mark Twain, except that he tends to use dialects that are not mainstream English).

Comment: This would make for a much more interesting and useful question if you asked *In what ways has the English language changed since the mid-eighteenth century?* As the title is worded, a simple "Yes, it has changed" is sufficient, and pretty well obvious. Every single language that is ALIVE has changed in the past 150 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question should be formulated:

***Has the*** English language changed **from 1854 to now**?

The language has changed considerably, yes.

It's not Old English, which is much earlier, but it's different from today.

A great book, though.

Also:

--  I read this book by a dictionary and write each word what I learn in a notebook

should be changed to:

*I read this book **with** a dictionary and write each word **that** I learn in a notebook*

That's going to help you.

Your notebook, is it paper-based or /electronic/a PC/?

If it's a PC, I'd suggest to get an electronic version of the book, convert it in Word, then use footnotes for any explanations.

Comment: I am really like to learn English. But I think its hard and I can't learn it well as native speakers. Can you please suggest me some tutorials?

Comment: See this for grammar http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/ , also http://goo.gl/RPTgTf.